# matlab convert subwindow into vector

Tags: matlab, image-processing

```
% obtain small windows of the image (say 16x16 windows and possibly using the crop function)
[rows columns] = size(B);
blockSizeR = 25; % Rows in block.
blockSizeC = 25; % Columns in block.
wholeBlockRows = floor(rows / blockSizeR);
wholeBlockCols = floor(columns / blockSizeC);
image3d = zeros(wholeBlockRows, wholeBlockCols);
sliceNumber = 1;
dataStruct = [];
for row = 1 : blockSizeR : rows
    for col = 1 : blockSizeC : columns
        row1 = row;
        row2 = row1 + blockSizeR - 1;
        col1 = col;
        col2 = col1 + blockSizeC - 1;
        oneBlock = B(row1:row2, col1:col2);
        subplot(4, 4, sliceNumber);
        imshow(oneBlock);
        caption = sprintf('Block #%d of 16', sliceNumber);
        title(caption);
        drawnow;
        dataStruct = [dataStruct, oneBlock(:)];
        sliceNumber = sliceNumber + 1;
    end
end
```

I am trying to extract 16 25x25 subwindows from a 100x100 pixel image, then convert each subwindow into a 125 column vector, but my data structure for appending all these vectors seem to be 625 x 16 instead of 125 x 16.

The subwindows seem to be displayed fine in the figure. Any clues as to where i went wrong would be much appreciated.

Comment: 25*25=625, how can it be a 125 column vector?

Comment: Agreed with Parag. Your code looks fine.

Comment: OH. MY. GOD. I AM SO SORRY

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mat2cell` and `cellfun`:

```
dataStruct = mat2cell( B, blockSizeR * ones(  1, wholeBlockRows ), ...
                          blockSizeC * ones(  1, wholeBlockCols ) );
dataStruct = cellfun( @(x) x(:), dataStruct, 'uni', 0 );
dataStruct = [dataStruct{:}];
```